# Howto display localized characters

Tags: mysql, android, http, character-encoding

I have a MySQL database, php code to retrieve from the database, and an Android program that recieve the output from the php code via http post.

My localized characters displays as question marks in my program.  I have tried different charsets in my database.  utf8_general_ci, utf8_unicode_ci, latin1_general_ci - still questions marks.  In html I could use the code ø, but not in an Android program - and I shouldn't have to.

First of all, where is this problem comming from?  The database itself have no problems displaying localized characters with utf8_.  Android also have no problems.  Is it the http post request or php that have problems with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would check layer by layer:

- Even the DB encoding is UTF8 - you are sure the value is properly stored?
- Do you have a way to test case the API (i.e. by using a web interface), if needed you would do packet inspection and check the proper UTF-8 value
- Is your PHP API sending the correct encoding?
- When reading the HTTP response in Android (i.e. parsing the Stream), are you supplying a encoding & is it the correct one?

Comment: After going at it step by step, testing things that didn't even make  sense, I figured out a solution. Setting the character code on the input stream to ISO-8859-1 ( latin1 ). Still though the DB is UTF8.  Dunno if this could have ambiguous results later but it works for now.

Comment: Setting the character encoding in my XML file to ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF worked for me